# Suggestions for finishing off bathtub ledge

Tags: bathroom, renovation

We are doing a bathroom renovation. We have put a tile ledge at the foot of the existing bathtub. I’m looking for ideas on how best to close up the side panel. Plan was to use fiber cement board screwed in to the existing framing. Even then I’m not completely sure on how best to close up the edge between the top of the board and the edge of the tile.

The panel needs to be removal as during this renovation we found a bunch of wiring that needs to be accessible. Old houses.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Attached photo to highlight the space and angle.
[image][image]

Comment: Are there wire *connections* under there?

Answer (score 1):

Take a piece of corner tile and seal it to the top of your ledge so it overhangs your removable cement board. See picture below.

[image]

They come in all sorts of lengths. Tile your removable cement board and fit it  up under the corner overhang.  Think about taking a 2" strip of cement board and screwing it to the framing in contact with the floor and wall so you could caulk it to the floor and wall to prevent water from getting in there. Your removable piece would fit on top of the strip and under the corner piece.

Answer (score 0):

To make good looking angles between your tiles you can use a profile like this:

[image]

I don't know exactly how it is called in English, but the picture should be self-explanatory. It is an extruded plastic or aluminium profile ([examples](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=profil%C3%A9%20angle%20carrelage&t=brave&iax=images&ia=images)). The visible part makes a nice angle, and it has a part that sticks out under the tile and is held in place by thinset.

If you've never used one of these choose a plastic one, it's easier to cut and work with.

Comment: Not suitable in this instance though. Not removable and not a tiled angle.

Comment: You can put a [removable tiled hatch](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=trappe+de+visite+carrelage&t=brave&iax=images&ia=images) on your panel to access whatever is behind it. I assumed you'd tile the panel for good looks.

Comment: Agree, installing an access panel is the only way to finish off the tiles properly, trouble is, unless you fit a big one, you'd need an electrician with gynaecological experience if anything went wrong in there!

Comment: LOL. Maybe the wiring could be accessed from under the sink? If there is a cupboard under the sink, that would be a lot easier to hide...